# Java in memory object caching with querying capabilities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, caching

I am building a service which is going to receive http requests with some querying params that will then need to apply into a set of objects and return matching objects back.

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/users?name=.*ith.*&age=lt(20)
```

That should return back all users that contain "ith" in their name and are less than 20 years of age.

All users will be loaded in memory from a DB upon service startup and all queries should be run against the in memory object set.

What would be the right technologies to use for that task?

I came across in memory DB H2 which could be fronted by hibernate and use hql for the querying but maybe that is an overkill.

Are there any caching frameworks that can store pure java objects and perform queries against them?

Thanks

Comment: It could be as simple as an ordinary Java collection.

Comment: If you want JPA and objects, then [ObjectDB](https://www.objectdb.com/) might be worth a look at, although it's not in-memory and don't know if it'll suit your workload.

Comment: Robert I don't want to write from scratch the query translation framework. We already have a framework that translates query params to sql so ideally I would like to reuse it

Comment: populating an in memory db for this purpose looks like an overkill to me; you need sth simpler. even if you want to go with an in memory db; I would go with `mybatis` instead of `hibernate`; since `hibernate` is even more overkill :)

@NikosDim have you checked this one: https://github.com/npgall/cqengine
it looks promising